# How to edit itemprop in div class in CSS? (Wordpress)

Tags: css, html, wordpress

I would like to change the font size of this, this has paragraph tags within. How do I change it? I am using wordpress and I can add custom CSS to fix this.

Here is my wordpress site that I am trying to fix using Inspect Element in Chrome and Firebug in Firefox. http://defensionem.com/2015/09/14/us-military-demo-3/

```
 <div class="body-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
```

I tried using this, but no avail.

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"]
 {font-size:32px;}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Problem is elsewhere, maybe CSS is overridden by `!important `

Comment: why `div` is not closed

Comment: Manoj, you are right. I found around 394 "!important" in my css file.

Comment: Nice, Dinesh! :) You can now answer this question and mark it.

Comment: Well, but Manoj bhai, It did not solve my issue. Here is my site link, http://defensionem.com/2015/09/14/us-military-demo-3/. I am trying to increase the font size and line height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using CSS Attribute Selectors, such as:

**Html**

```
<div class="body-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody"><h1>Test</h1>
```

**Css**

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h1 {
color: red;
}
```

and

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] h1 {
 color: yellow;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bEUk8/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..

This will help you..

```css
div[itemprop="articleBody"] {
  font-size: 32px!important;
  color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @DineshGupta the snippet shows that it works so if there is another problem than explain so that we can help you

Comment: As Manoj said, something seems to be overwriting it. In my style.css file by the Wordpress theme.

Comment: so in your css you can look yourself or paste your code here so we can help you

Comment: The CSS code by Wordpress is around 5,000 lines long. Anyway here it is.

Comment: @DineshGupta you can add `!important` to override your css again

Comment: @Amit I did the downvote. Suggest to fix the problem by `!important` **without explaining that it's a bad practice** encourage terrible coding practices that made the OP in this exact position.

Comment: @vard he already mentioned that his css is overriden by some css of wordpress and he also mentioned the he had used 394 !important in his css so i suggest him to use !important and i know it is bad practice but this only seems his problem is fixed

Comment: @Amit Suggest to use `!important` if *there is no other workaround* is ok. But it should **always** come with a little explanation of why **it's wrong**. Without any warning of that kind, OP will continue to use `!important` everywhere and make his life and others life difficult.

Comment: @vard this is updated answer i had posted the answer without !important first and he mentioned that he is familier with use of !important so i edited and added this answer

Comment: @Amit I don't see what it change in the end.

Comment: @vard what do you want ? if you think you are the best than answer it ? if not than you don't have authority to downvote others

Comment: @Amit Why getting so mad about a downvote? You ask the reason why, I explained. Downvotes are about question / answer quality, it's not personal. And I have all the authority to downvote your answer as this is how SO is working : people vote up good answers and vote down bad quality one...

Comment: if the asker had told that this answer doesn't work than i would have accept it and he can downvote.

Comment: without any reason you are downvoting me because i didn't answer your question so badly and if the asker downvoted me than i would take that positive

Comment: if other user of SO has thought that this answer is bad than they would have downvoted me

Comment: Few things then I'm done with this. 1. I didn't downvoted you without any reason and explained why I did. If you can't take this as constructive I can't do anything for you. 2. SO is about building cannonical answers - think about other users that can come around in the future and see your answer. 3. Everyone can downvote, not only the OP. He's not the only judge of your answer quality. 4. Stop take it personnal.